# Is it ok to feed dog weight loss food?

Tags: dogs, diet

I accidentally bought some food that was intended for "less active or overweight" dogs and mixed it with equal amounts of normal food. The less active one said 75% rdi on the back, and from what I can gather it is just the normal one but buffed up with fiber to make each serve less calories overall. I might be wrong though.

My dog is very skinny and a very active terrier. She likes to run all over the place. Would it be ok to feed her the food for a long time?

Comment: well a long time would only be while the mixed food supply lasts. How long do you think that would be?

Comment: Does the food have a guaranteed analysis label which shows the proteins, fats & such? Is it AAFCO approved with feeding and formula trials? If not, can you return it or donate it to a local kennel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much. While she's on it weigh her weekly to see if she's losing weight, if so you will have to either:

a) Feed her more

b) Supplement it with her regular kibble